# Framework for shell like command line interactive application

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to write my own interactive shell for Linux.

- limited set of my own commands
- no need to execute external binaries

It is not hard to do it, but I would like to do somethimg more user friendly.

- TAB auto completion
- interactive line editing
- history of last commands

Is there some library/framework/minimal shell that can be used for this? 
So I don't need to write everything myself.

Prefered license is some permissive (MIT, BSD, Apache, ..)

Prefered language is python, c, c++, javascript or sh

Comment: One might argue this to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883467/is-there-a-simple-alternative-to-readline -- any answer there would also be an acceptable answer here -- though with modern site rules that question would no longer be allowed.

Comment: If I knew readline, I would have google it myself.

Comment: Sure -- folks not knowing the right keywords is why we *want* good duplicate questions (that is, duplicates that ask the question in a way that someone who _didn't_ know the keywords would, and in a way that differs significantly from any other ways the same question was previously asked on the site) -- we mark them close-as-duplicate, and then they provide a pointer/signpost to the canonical answer, thus adding value to the knowledge base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python, the standard-library `cmd` module does this: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/cmd.html

For C, you have several options available for managing interactive editing, history, and tab completion:

- [`readline`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline), used by bash itself, but GPL-licensed.
- [`editline`](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/), a widespread BSD alternative.
- [`linenoise`](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise), a newer alternative.

---

By the way -- this question is explicitly off-topic; I expect it to be closed.

Comment: Anyway, thank you. I just didn't know where to start and where to ask. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you need job control (i.e. backgrounding) you can have a look at the glibc manual [on Implementing a Shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Implementing-a-Shell.html#Implementing-a-Shell).

Comment: Since the OP specifies "no need to execute external binaries", there's clearly no need to support executing them in the background. Nonetheless, that's an interesting link.

Comment: He can also have a look at the sources of bash: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/ . A shell that does not need to execute external binaries is quite limited as it lacks any useful functionality(or it can provide it on its own but that wouldn't make it a shell any more(imagine all binaries such as mkdir, cd, ld, ls, cat, touch, file, etc. put together in one)).

Comment: Reading the question in context, the goal is clearly less a shell in the sense that you're thinking of, and more an interactive command line / REPL for a non-shell piece of software.